# Responsive SVG path without distorting stroke

Tags: javascript, css, animation, svg, svg-animate

I have a simple SVG path with a stroke that I want to responsively resize with the browser window. The problem is that when I scale the path, the stroke is distorted because stroke-dashoffset is not the same regardless of the scaling.
if there is a way to solve the problem with pure SVG (and CSS) or I need use javascript to update the path?

```js
(function() {
  var charParts, i, j, len, part, partElem, resize;

  charParts = ["d-1", "d-2", "e-1", "e-2", "s-1", "i-1", "i-2", "g-1", "g-2", "n-1", "n-2"];

  partElem = $("path");

  for (j = 0, len = charParts.length; j < len; j++) {
    part = charParts[j];
    $("svg").append(partElem.clone().attr("class", part));
  }

  setTimeout(function() {
    return $("div").toggleClass("text");
  }, 100);

$("button").click(function(e){
      $("div").toggleClass("scaled");
})

}).call(this);
```

```css
body,
html,
div {
  background: #5677fc;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}
div {
  transform: scale(0.5);
  transition: all 500ms linear 0s;
}
.scaled {
  transform: scale(1);
}
svg {
  width: 600px;
  height: 400px;
  cursor: pointer;
  -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  -moz-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  -o-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  -ms-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
}
path {
  fill: none;
  -webkit-transition: stroke-dashoffset 5.5s cubic-bezier(0.445, 0.05, 0.55, 0.95), stroke-dasharray 5.5s cubic-bezier(0.445, 0.05, 0.55, 0.95);
  -moz-transition: stroke-dashoffset 5.5s cubic-bezier(0.445, 0.05, 0.55, 0.95), stroke-dasharray 5.5s cubic-bezier(0.445, 0.05, 0.55, 0.95);
  -o-transition: stroke-dashoffset 5.5s cubic-bezier(0.445, 0.05, 0.55, 0.95), stroke-dasharray 5.5s cubic-bezier(0.445, 0.05, 0.55, 0.95);
  -ms-transition: stroke-dashoffset 5.5s cubic-bezier(0.445, 0.05, 0.55, 0.95), stroke-dasharray 5.5s cubic-bezier(0.445, 0.05, 0.55, 0.95);
  transition: stroke-dashoffset 5.5s cubic-bezier(0.445, 0.05, 0.55, 0.95), stroke-dasharray 5.5s cubic-bezier(0.445, 0.05, 0.55, 0.95);
  stroke-width: 2px;
  stroke-linecap: round;
  stroke: #f5f6f7;
  stroke-dashoffset: 0px;
  stroke-dasharray: 0px 1180px;
}
.text path.d-1 {
  stroke-dashoffset: -149px;
  stroke-dasharray: 22px 1180px;
}
.text path.d-2 {
  stroke-dashoffset: -201.3px;
  stroke-dasharray: 49px 1180px;
}
.text path.e-1 {
  stroke-dashoffset: -377.5px;
  stroke-dasharray: 14px 1180px;
}
.text path.e-2 {
  stroke-dashoffset: -431.2px;
  stroke-dasharray: 43px 1180px;
}
.text path.s-1 {
  stroke-dashoffset: -526px;
  stroke-dasharray: 37px 1180px;
}
.text path.i-1 {
  stroke-dashoffset: -631px;
  stroke-dasharray: 0.1px 1180px;
}
.text path.i-2 {
  stroke-dashoffset: -637.5px;
  stroke-dasharray: 16px 1180px;
}
.text path.g-1 {
  stroke-dashoffset: -732.5px;
  stroke-dasharray: 15px 1180px;
}
.text path.g-2 {
  stroke-dashoffset: -812px;
  stroke-dasharray: 69px 1180px;
}
.text path.n-1 {
  stroke-dashoffset: -941px;
  stroke-dasharray: 17px 1180px;
}
.text path.n-2 {
  stroke-dashoffset: -1013px;
  stroke-dasharray: 33.5px 1180px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button>Scale</button>
<div>
  <svg viewBox="0 0 300 200">
    <path class="motion" d="
      M  0,  0
      C  0,  0  99,  1  99, 89
      L 99,111
      C 99,130  75,112  99,112
      C103,112 100,112 106,112
      C121,112 121, 89 105, 89
      C 88, 89 102, 89  99, 89
      C  0, 89  80,103 123,103
      C128,103 135,103 136,103
      C155,103 137,140 137,103
      C137, 92 123, 93 123,103
      C123,115 135,113 137,110
      C152, 86 103, 87 143,110
      C152,116 157,106 147,103
      C140,102 143, 93 152, 96
      C206,118 159.5,50 159,89
      L159,112
      C159,180 117, 93 168,118
      C176,122 180,116 180,115
      C183,107 169,101 168, 90
      C167, 77 180, 67 180, 95
      L180,103
      C180,115 166,115 166,103
      C166, 92 180, 94 180,102
      C180,180 188,125 188,112
      C188,110 188,100 188, 96
      C188, 91 189, 80 194, 91
      C200,101 186,134 188,106
      C189, 93 201, 93 201,100
      C201,105 201,105 201,112
      C201,130 220,160 300, 80
    "></path>
  </svg>
</div>
```

[image][image]

Comment: What do you mean by distorted?  I tried Chrome and Firefox.  I don't see any behaviour difference between the scaled and unscaled SVGs on either browser.  The dashes don't move when you toggle the scale.

Comment: Maybe it's me, but i fail to see any difference

Comment: Add a screenshot of what trouble you are facing that will be the easiest way to convey your problem to others.

Comment: I put  screenshots for better understanding